# use Model Methodes in external php file

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have a php file which is placed within the Opencart root (2.0.1.1).

I want to add a new language with the OC methods.

According to *admin/index.php* and *model || controller/localisation/language.php* i shall adjust

```
require_once($root . 'admin/config.php'); 
require_once($root . 'system/startup.php');
// Registry
$registry = new Registry();
// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);
// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);
// Database
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, DB_PORT);
$registry->set('db', $db);
// Settings
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0'");
foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
if (!$setting['serialized']) {
$config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
} else {
$config->set($setting['key'], json_decode($setting['value'], true));
}
}
//STARTING NOW, $langu instead of $this
$data = array("name"=>"slovak","code"=>"sk","lokal"=>"sk-SK",..);
$langu = new Language();
$langu->load->model('localisation/language');
$langu->model_localisation_language->addLanguage($data);
```

this doesn't work. it results in

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant DB_PORT - assumed 'DB_PORT' in
>   **/path/opencart/admin/controller/module/_account22/account22_getLangZipUnzip.php**
>   on line **21**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined property:
>   Language::$load in
>   **/path/opencart/admin/controller/module/_account22/account22_getLangZipUnzip.php**
>   on line **108**
>  
>  **Fatal error**:  Call to a member
>   function language() on a non-object in
>   **/path/opencart/admin/controller/module/_account22/account22_getLangZipUnzip.php**
>   on line **108**

Fatal Error is at *$langu->load->model('localisation/language');*

Answer (score 0):

The Language class has a load function but you are using it like it is a property of the Language class. It appears that you are trying to use the coding style that is used by Controller classes.

Comment: thx for the hint. Could you be more specific with some working code? thanks for that